# Copying a built framework into Python package with package_data

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to improve the way that [PyBluez](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez) installs on macOS. [Here](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/2f8636de6bb1b0162862b97dcf67e5ccd0fc5922/setup.py#L84) is what the setup.py code looks like today, before my changes.

In short, on macOS an extra package called `lightblue` is installed, and this depends on a framework called LightAquaBlue.framework. Today, it invokes xcodebuild to build the framework and install it to `/Library/Frameworks`, but I want to change it to embed the framework within the Python package.

Here's what I've done:

```
packages.append('lightblue')
package_dir['lightblue'] = 'osx'
install_requires += ['pyobjc-core>=3.1', 'pyobjc-framework-Cocoa>=3.1']

# Add the LightAquaBlue framework to the package data as an 'eager resource'
# so that we can extract the whole framework at runtime
package_data['lightblue'] = [ 'LightAquaBlue.framework' ]
eager_resources.append('LightAquaBlue.framework')

# FIXME: This is inelegant, how can we cover the cases?
if 'install' in sys.argv or 'bdist' in sys.argv or 'bdist_egg' in sys.argv:
    # Build the framework into osx/
    import subprocess
    subprocess.check_call([
        'xcodebuild', 'install',
        '-project', 'osx/LightAquaBlue/LightAquaBlue.xcodeproj',
        '-scheme', 'LightAquaBlue',
        'DSTROOT=' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'osx'),
        'INSTALL_PATH=/',
        'DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES',
    ])
```

This builds the LightAquaBlue.framework inside `osx/` (which is the `lightblue` package's directory) and then passes it to setuptools as `package_data`. However, when I run `pip install --upgrade -v ./pybluez/`, the LightAquaBlue.framework is *not* copied:

```
creating build/lib/lightblue
copying osx/_bluetoothsockets.py -> build/lib/lightblue
copying osx/_LightAquaBlue.py -> build/lib/lightblue
copying osx/_obexcommon.py -> build/lib/lightblue
copying osx/_IOBluetoothUI.py -> build/lib/lightblue
copying osx/__init__.py -> build/lib/lightblue
copying osx/_IOBluetooth.py -> build/lib/lightblue
copying osx/_obex.py -> build/lib/lightblue
copying osx/_lightblue.py -> build/lib/lightblue
copying osx/obex.py -> build/lib/lightblue
copying osx/_macutil.py -> build/lib/lightblue
copying osx/_lightbluecommon.py -> build/lib/lightblue
```

If I have setup.py create a dummy file inside `osx/`, and add it to `package_data`, it *does* get copied. This suggests to me there's no confusion over paths.

If I add `os.system('ls osx/')`, it also shows me that LightAquaBlue.framework is present in the same place as my dummy file.

```
    LightAquaBlue
--> LightAquaBlue.framework
    DUMMY_FILE_THAT_WORKS
    _IOBluetooth.py
    _IOBluetoothUI.py
    _LightAquaBlue.py
    __init__.py
    _bluetoothsockets.py
    _lightblue.py
    _lightbluecommon.py
    _macutil.py
    _obex.py
    _obexcommon.py
   obex.py
```

Why isn't the framework correctly copied in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like setuptools' documentation [contradicts the implementation](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1198) and actually **you cannot specify a directory to include in `package_data`**.

It's not very elegant, but I used:

```
# We can't seem to list a directory as package_data, so we will
# recursively add all all files we find
package_data['lightblue'] = []
for path, _, files in os.walk('osx/LightAquaBlue.framework'):
    for f in files:
        include = os.path.join(path, f)[4:]  # trim off osx/
        package_data['lightblue'].append(include)
```